# Repetir trigger ejecutado al minuto de producirse

Tags: script, trigger, google-apps-script

Llevo días intentando..
Mi codigo .gs es:

```
function myFunctione(e) { 
var url = 'https://example.com/?iwp=run';   
var options = { 'method': 'get' }; 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); 
Logger.log(response); }
```

Se activa al producirse un cambio en la planilla. 
Pero necesito que se ejecute otra vez al minuto de producirse, alguna sugerencia?

Intente asi pero no algo esta mal.El problema es que no se ejecuta por un error Por eso no puedo verlo. Como puedo hacer para que sólo se ejecute una vez y no un bucle con for?

```
 var delay_ms = [1000,2000];

 function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
 for (var i = delay_ms.length-1; i >=0; i++){ //reverse loop in order to 
get the current trigger right
var TriggerID= ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunctione") 
     .timeBased()
  .after(delay_ms[i]) 
  .create()
  .getUniqueId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(TriggerID, 
 delay_ms.length-i-1);//
  }
 }
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Mencionas que deseas que el activador se active un minuto después pero los tiempos indicados son 1 y 2 segundos. Un minuto tiene `60000` milisegundos.  Por otro lado, estás usando un bucle para crear triggers, ¿has revisado cuantos triggers se han creado? ¿Has revisado el transcript de ejecución?

Comment: Hola Rubén. El problema es que no se ejecuta por esta línea en error 'var TriggerID= ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunctione") '. Por eso no puedo verlo. Como puedo hacer para que sólo se ejecute una vez y no un bucle con for?

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para tener claro que es lo que requieres. Me parece que estás empezando con Google Apps Script / JavaScript ¿es correcto?

Comment: He visto tu edición. Esta mas claro, pero cabe hacer notar que el comando al que te refieres abarca mas de una línea. Ayudaría a darte una respuesta mas precisa a la que ya te dí que incluyeras el mensaje textual de error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como deseas que se ejecute un minuto después, en lugar de usar un activador usa

```
Utilities.sleep(60000)
```

Esto porque la hora en la que se ejecuta un activador programado tiene una variación de +/- 15 minutos.

Para esto, se podría usar una función "orquestadora" que llame tu función, el comando indicado y luego vuelva a llamar tu función, por ejemplo, algo así:

```
function director(){
  myFunction();
  Utilities.sleep(60 *1000);
  myFunction();
}
```

Deberás cambiar tu activador al editar la hoja de cálculo para que en lugar de llamar `myFunction` llame `director`. Si procedes de esta forma `createTimeDrivenTriggers` no se requiere.

---

Traducción de https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)

> **after(durationMilliseconds)**
>
> Especifica la duración (en milisegundos) después de la hora actual en la que el activador será ejecutado ( más / menos 15 minutos)
>
> ```
> ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
>   .timeBased()
>   .after(10 * 60 * 1000)
>   .create();
> ```

Comment: Gracias Ruben, Yo he configurado manualmente la funcion myFunctione() cuando se edita. La funcion director se ejecuta automaticamente con el script ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunctione")? Porque no corre... y como haria para que no sea repetitivo y solo una vez?

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Punto y aparte que no era del todo clara y que aún se podria mejorar, me parece que debes aprender lo básico de JavaScript. Quizás te sirva [Primeros pasos con JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps)

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben! Me ayudaste mucho funciono perfecto!!!